# jQuery horizontal scrolling site, with scrollTo behaviour

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have used the jInvertScroll plugin to create a horizontally-scrolling site. However, I also want a behaviour where a user could click an element and the screen would animate to centre on it, horizontally.

I have tried this solution:

```
$('body, html').animate({
        scrollLeft: $("#img").offset().top
        });
```

...but I can't get it to work horizontally.

I have tried to use the ScrollTo plugin, but the plugins don't seem to be compatible, as they require different position values. Actually, all I've got now is that whenever you press the button to make it focus on the element, the whole page scrolls to the right about 400 pixels.

Does anyone know of a way I could create a horizontal site that also animates to certain hoironztal points on click?

Answer (score 0):

I dont get a point of clicking something which user can actually see to center on it, but here is an example how you can animate scroll horizontally to element.

Mabey it will help you.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var start_position = $('.first').offset().left;
  var element_position = $('.scroll').offset().left;

  if (start_position > 0) {
    $('.demo').animate({
      scrollLeft: start_position + element_position
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $('.demo').animate({
      scrollLeft: -1 * start_position + element_position
    }, 1000);
  }

  return false;
});
```

```css
.demo {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.demo img {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="first" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Westminstpalace.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/mcmurdoiceberg_pho_2017333_lrg.jpg">
    <img class="scroll" src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/pia21975-opt.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/36782365195_b7fcd1480c_o.jpg">
<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/assasn-14li_banner_0.jpg">
  </div>

</div>

<button>
Scroll to
</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, much appreciated. Although this works, I get some weird behaviour if I click-drag the scrollbar to a random point, and then press the button. It seems to animate the div to different random points, and I can't work out why.

Comment: The reason of that behaviour is position of .scroll element is calculated from left border of scrollable window. I have updated my code, now it's calculating position from first element.